# Adding a Javascript alert on successful form submission - VB.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, post, alert

I'm trying to add an alert when a user submits a form. I want it to only show the alert when the submit is successful, otherwise I would just attach a javascript alert to the submit button. I followed the method suggested here:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dsplay-Alert-Message-in-ASPNet-from-code-behind-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

but the alert part isn't working. I tried putting the alert code in the Page_Load and it worked, but when I put it in the button click handler, I don't get any alert.

```
Public Sub Send_Data(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNewsletter.Click
    Dim sFName, sLName As String
    Dim sEmail As String
    Dim clsUser As New clsLogin
    Dim iConfirm As Integer

    sEmail = email.Text
    If sEmail = "" Then Exit Sub
    Try
        If clsUser.Check_Cookie = False Then
            iConfirm = clsUser.Create_Acct("", "", sEmail, "", iType)
        End If
        clsUser.Add_AvailLog(0, iType, iChat)
    Catch
    End Try

    'start JK

    Dim blog As Destinations.GetBlog
    Dim TargetURL As String
    TargetURL = "http://wimco.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=fe50a5183f6f54bb70a7005e3&id=b2e21157fc"

    Dim html As String
    Dim PostData As String

    PostData = "&EMAIL=" & sEmail & "&b_fe50a5183f6f54bb70a7005e3_b2e21157fc=&subscribe=Subscribe"

    html = blog.PostData(TargetURL, PostData)

    email.Text = ""

    ' This is the alert section
    Dim message As String = "Order Placed Successfully."
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("alert('")
    sb.Append(message)
    sb.Append("');")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing something similar to this and your code looks ok.

Have you tried to debug your code and made sure the code reaches the end of the Send_Data function where RegisterClientScriptBlock is called?

I have a feeling it stopped at If sEmail = "" Then Exit Sub.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the alert to the page which is shown after the submitted page.